# Relating Hazelcast map and CP Subsystem

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am working with maps in Hazelcast. I came to know that hazelcast cp subsystem only supports cp data structures like fencedlock, atomiclong etc. and guarantees consistency only for those.
Is there a way I can relate the data in the Hazelcast map and the CP subsystem such that I can use the cp subsystem to verify the consistency of my map data.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/hazelcast/c/vNK5xEkruqg/m/uKIg0UFrAAAJ) and [Hazelcast Community Slack](https://hazelcastcommunity.slack.com/archives/C015Q2TUBKL/p1659501876168679)

TL;DR - "not yet"